How are indirect questions introduced by quam?
Can indirect questions be introduced by quam? What mood to they take?
My professor says that they can and that is is within my grammar book, but I cannot find it and chegg seems to state that quam cannot be used:
https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/latin-indirect-questions-introduced-quam-mood-verb-q217998096
Is my professor wrong? Is chegg incorrect? How can quam be used with indirect questions?

Quam can certainly introduce direct and indirect questions, and if they're indirect, then they're in the subjunctive like all indirect questions.
As an interrogative adverb:

Cicero poscit quam diu furor Catilinae senatum elusurus sit. (Direct: Quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet?)

As a relative adjective:

Consul rogat, quam rem publicam habeamus. (Direct: Quam rem publicam habemus?)


+1 but can posco really be used with quam?

@Cerberus that was probably a little bold of me but cf. Verg. Aen. 3, 59: quae sit sententia posco.

@Sebastian Koppehel: In the first direct expression why use "iste" = "that thing of yours" and "tuus" = "your" together? In Caesar's (reported) last words, as Cimber grabbed his arm, "ista quidem vis est", "ista", alone, is considered to be sufficient.

@tony I think it's for emphasis, just as in English you could say "that fury of yours." Furor iste perhaps sounds a little more contemptuous than just furor.

@Cerberus: Why are you surprised that Seb has used "posco" with "quam"--is it because they are both interrogatives?

@tony I take the scrupulum Cerbereum to be whether the verb poscere should be followed by an indirect question at all, and that does indeed seem to be much rarer than I thought and not really suitable for an instructive example. It does not really matter, though. Imagine any verbum rogandi in its place.

@SebastianKoppehel: Nice find in poetry, and that was indeed what prompted me.

Would this be an indirect question with quam: Quaero quam longē ambulāvistī? - I ask how far did you walk?

@user2231142 in principle, yes, but all indirect questions must be in the subjunctive, so it must be ambulaveris.
